# Flexbox columns, titles and positioning

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having some trouble with my flexbox layout.
I have created a pen for you to look at:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/PqONKq

What I am attempting to do is create 2 columns. In each column there are some "boxes". These boxes should be spaced evenly, be square and line from top to bottom wrapping onto the next line where they start from the top again.
As you can see from my codepen I nearly have it, except the wrapped items are not spaced as I would like. I tried using:

```
align-content: flex-start;
```

on the **.flex-column** but that didn't work. I also tried:

```
justify-content: flex-start;
```

but that also did nothing.

The other issue is that I want to have titles in my columns, but as soon as I add one it messes everything up (as you can imagine).

So my question is twofold:

1. How can I arrange my boxes properly so they align to the top of the columns?
2. How can I add a title that will not mess up my boxes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.box { margin: 0 auto auto auto; }` sticks box #1 where you want but then there's a full height of gutter at bottom. Woudl this be OK?

Answer (score 1):

Your flex items are not aligned to the top because you use `margin: auto`.

But if you remove that, the flex items in the first column won't be evenly spaced.

Using `justify-content: space-around` you would have the same problem.

Instead, you can try `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px 20px 20px;
}
.flex-column {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 320px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is fine if it is only one column, but I want the columns to wrap onto the next line. I have updated my codepen with your solution and you should be able to see the issue.

Comment: @r3plica The only problem I see is that you increased the number of flex items, so now they overflow `.flex-column`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the solution to this problem was to have margin around the items.
**justify-content** needs to be set to **flex-start** in order to keep the items in the correct alignment for wrapping.
The columns have to be set explicitly which isn't a problem for me, because I was working this out anyway.
My codepen has been updated with the changes.